# Does Tor now keep history?

Tags: anonymity

The latest update seems to have changed settings to keeping history. Is it also broadcasting our social security #'s?

Answer (score 0):

Just checked, Tor Browser doesn't keeps the history by default. You probably changed the settings.

Also, I'm not aware of **any** browser broadcasting social security numbers. So, yeah. Tor doesn't do it either.

If in doubt you can also check the source code: https://gitweb.torproject.org/

Comment: Also make sure that you are really using the real Tor Browser. If it doesn't come from here, then it might be fake: https://www.torproject.org/download/